# Not able to create rooms using Exchange Webservice Managed API

Tags: exchangewebservices, ews-managed-api

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/hh532568(v=exchg.80).aspx

Why does Exchange Webservices Managed API does not support creating of rooms?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EWS is a Mailbox Access API for accessing Mailbox data as a user (like MAPI,IMAP,POP etc). Creating Mailboxes,Meeting Room, contacts, distribution groups are administrative functions so you need to use an administrative API.

Comment: thank you for giving some light and your active response Glen Scales.